# I cannot find restore command in joomla

Tags: joomla, restore

I installed the joomla extension, akeeba-8.0.4-core.zip.
Then I backed up my site.
I need to restore the backed up site, but I can't find the return button.
https://joom.team/en/restoring-a-joomla-website-from-a-backup
Here, as shown in Figure 1, there is a restore item.
However, it cannot be found as shown in Figure 2.
I hope for help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNycq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYkGu.png)

Comment: It looks like they have restore button for Professional version only. You can check this post - https://www.akeeba.com/support/akeeba-backup-3x/Ticket/8797:no-restore-option-in-administer-files-area.html

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your joomla-related questions in that dedicated community. @Atene